# Tomcat Servlet: Error 404 with netbeans

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404, tomcat8

This happens when I try to run my program. I have already edited web.xml file as required.

> HTTP Status 404 - /WebApplication1/hello
>
> type Status report
>
> message /WebApplication1/hello
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.0.30

Comment: What is the welcome file list in web.xml? It seems /hello is for servlet, then what is your servlet mapping tag?

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>Hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Is the class mentioned in <servlet-class> tag present? Also please try accessing /WebApplication1/Hello, as URLs are case sensitive.

Comment: OMG thanks...Indeed it was case sensitive issue..I was going insane trying what not to fix the issue..:L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please access

> /WebApplication1/Hello

as URLs are case sensitive.